# Many To One relationship not working in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I have set the relationship on the entity's to set many customers to a user entity as a collection and added Multiple to the form field...it's posting ok it's just not updating the user_id in the customer table but it was when using OneToOne relation. Any help would be appreciated.

User entity code

```
/**
     * @var Customer[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Customer", mappedBy="user", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $customer;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->staffUsers = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->customer = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
     * @param Collection|null $customer
     * @return $this
     */

    public function setCustomer(?Collection $customer): self
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;

        return $this;
    }
```

Customer entity code

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="customer", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $user;


  /**
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param User|null $user
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }
```

Controller code

```
public function newUser(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder) : Response
    {

        /** @var UserRepository $userRepo */
        $userRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);
        $customer = new Customer();

        // make form
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class,new User());

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){

            /** @var User $newUser */
            $newUser = $form->getData();
            
//            dump($newUser);
//            die();

            // hold user roles
            $roles = ['ROLE_USER'];

            // check if admin role
            $adminRole = (bool)$form->get('adminRole')->getData();

            if($adminRole){
                $roles[]='ROLE_ADMIN';
            }

            // is a customer selected?
            if($newUser->getCustomer() && $newUser->getCustomer()->count() > 0){
                $roles[]='ROLE_CUSTOMER';
            }

            $newUser->setRoles($roles);

            // encode pw
            $newUser->setPassword(
                $encoder->encodePassword($newUser,$newUser->getPassword())
            );

            // create

            $userRepo->insert($newUser);


            return $this->redirectToRoute('usersListing');

        }

        return $this->render('admin/users/user-form.html.twig',[
            'form'=>$form->createView()
        ]);

    }
```

Customer entity type on User form

```
->add('customer',EntityType::class,[
                'required'=>false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'attr'=>[
                    'class'=>'selectpicker form-control',
                    'multiple' =>'multiple',
                    'data-width' => "100%"

                ],
                'label'=>'Customer(s)',
                'placeholder'=>'N/A',
                'class'=>Customer::class,
                'query_builder'=>function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->orderBy('c.lname', 'ASC')
                        ->orderBy('c.fname','ASC');
                },
                'constraints'=>[
                    new Callback(function(?Collection $customers, ExecutionContextInterface $context) use($userRepo){

                        // check if the customer is already linked to a user
                        if($customers && $customers->count() > 0){
                            /** @var Customer $customer */
                            foreach($customers as $customer){
                                if($customer->getUser()){
                                    $context->addViolation('Customer Is Already Linked To User: ' . $customer->getUser()->getUsername());
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }


                        return true;

                    })
                ]
            ])
```

Comment: This question has been asked so many times.  Perhaps a record?

Comment: in doctrine, you have to set the **owning side** of a relation, which in your case is the customer side. Meaning: `User::setCustomers($customers)` is insufficient, you need to set `Customer::setUser($user)`. you can integrate this stuff into the `setCustomers` by calling `setUser` on each customer, but it has to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Rename property **customer** to **customers** and function from **setCustomer** to **setCustomers**, you should also create an **addCustomer** method in your User class:

```
public function addCustomer(Customer $customer)
{
  $this->customers[] = $customer;
  $customer->setUser($this); // sets the owning side, without this your will end up with user_id equal to null
}
```

And whenever you want to add a customer you just invoke the addCustomer method.
If you want to use the **setCustomers** method **make sure you set the user in your customer entity**.